# Process Synchronization and counting semaphores

Tags: concurrency, process, synchronization, semaphore, critical-section

I am learning counting semaphores but fail to understand it. I've read almost all the articles but still have a hard time in understanding it.

Here is my understanding with toilet key example (http://niclasw.mbnet.fi/MutexSemaphore.html) 
Here,

Toilet - Critical Section

Key - Semaphore

Person - Process

Correct me If I am wrong in the above. My questions are:

1)"A semaphore restricts the number of simultaneous users of a shared resource up to a maximum number". Doesn't simultaneous access of a shared variable lead to race around condition?

2)After a semaphore is acquired by a process, will it be running in it Critical section?(Basing on the example)

3)If a process is in it CS and another process acquires semaphore,will it be running its CS concurrently or will it be waiting?

Excuse me if my questions are rudimentary but I am trying hard to understand it.Please explain semaphore with an EXAMPLE?

Answer (score 0):

let's say there's a vip room. there can be at most 3 people in the room. set your semaphore to 3.

the semaphore is your bodyguard to prevent the 4th person to enter the room.

how does it work? you can call two functions with a semaphore: `wait()` and `signal()`

`wait()` function simply **decreases** the semaphore value by 1. and if the new value is negative, it has to wait until the value is positive again.

so you started with semaphore = 3. with every person entering the room, it's decreased by 1.

person 1 enters...sem = 2

person 2 enters...sem = 1

person 3 enters...sem = 0

person 4 tries to enter but sem = -1 now, *our bodyguard will not let him in*. so, he has to wait. **until**, someone leaves the room!

when you're done with critical section, you `signal()` to let the outsider know that he can enter now. so as you can tell, this function **increases** the semaphore value by 1.

mutex is semaphore = 1.

thread A:

```
mutex.wait(); //makes mutex = 0
CS();
mutex.signal();
```

thread B:

```
mutex.wait(); //has to wait until A signals so the mutex = 1 again
CS();
mutex.signal();
```

with this implementation, while A is running, there's no way that B can reach the CS where he changes some global variable with a context switch. B has to wait until A is done. and vice versa.

to have more understanding with semaphores, you can check famous problems like producer&consumer, barbershop, dining philosophers... there are lots of them. i believe it's more fun that way and the scenarios help you to understand easier.
also, i think [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t0CnClz8Jo4) is quite useful.

hope this helps!